# RecyclerView inside SwipeRefreshLayout does not show

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout, recyclerview-layout

I implemented one horizontal-scroll item listview using RecyclerView inside scrollview. I want to update the item when user swipe to the end of the listview (item is added after refreshing). The following code is the layout implementation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager">

            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Before I add SwipeRefreshLayout, everything works fine (items in RecyclerView shown normally), but after I add SwipeRefreshLayout, RecyclerView is gone (both in the device and preview in Android Studio)

Could you figure out how to fix this problem. Thanks in advance!!

*EDIT*
Here are what I want to do
[image: Scroll itself]
[image: Refresy RecyclerView]

Comment: add SwipeRefreshLayout to parent and remove scroll view

Answer (score 12):

Try this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: A main layout should be scrollable. Actually there are many items inside ScrollView.

Comment: let swiperefresh layout be parent and add a nested scrollview inside that linearlayout and place your items there.

Comment: What about there are more than one RecyclerView with SwipeRefresh in the same page? Maybe I need to add some screenshot to make the problem clearer.

Comment: check the edited answer. You can add number of recyclerview like this.  But if you want to refresh each recyclerview separately i suggest you to have buttons in the gray portion of your screen shots.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using `SwipeRefreshLayout` inside `ScrollView` is creating Problem

Use this one working for me.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_animation"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false">
                </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

            </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```